# Safest way to sync local database to online db(phpmyadmin)?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

What will be the best solution to sync my local database (about 100 stations/localdb) to my live server.

I see this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74707/how-to-sync-local-mysql-database-and-live-server-database)  here and it seems too dangerous to use on my case.

Comment: There are lots of ways to sync multiple databases. We cannot tell you which one is the best for you, though. Try mysql's built-in replication first. If that does not work out for you, then look for alternatives. If you need help with mysql replication then please ask your questions on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO, as those questions will not be about software development!

Answer (score -1):

You should try mysql [triggers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-triggers/)

.

Comment: Triggers can sync data between tables on the same instance, but cannot be used to sync data with remote servers in isolation.